# Keep track of visit count in cookies

Tags: php, drupal, cookies, drupal-7

I would like to keep track of the number of visits for each anonymous user. I want to be able to show special messages, for example when they visit the site the 10th time.

Incrementing a cookie variable will just be fine in this case. How do I find out when a new session has started?

I'm using Drupal 7 but there doesn't seem to be a module for that available.

Comment: In future, please flag for a mod to migrate your question, please don't cross-post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you could use the Statistics module for that, like [Here](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid:119). In the case that doesn't suit your needs, you could create one. You could turn the following code into a module of your own.

```
$today = date('l, F j, Y');
$timestamp = date('g:i A');
if (strcmp($_COOKIE["LAST_VISIT"], '') == 0) {
  $lasttime = "";
}
else {
  $lasttime = $_COOKIE["LAST_VISIT"];
}

$LAST_VISIT = $today . " at " . $timestamp;

// Set the "LAST_VISIT" cookie with date/time, with expiration for 2 full weeks.
setcookie ("LAST_VISIT", $LAST_VISIT, time() + 3600*24*14);

if ($_COOKIE["VISIT_NUMBER"] == 0) {
  $visitcount = 0;
}
else {
  $visitcount = $_COOKIE[VISIT_NUMBER];
}

// Set the "VISIT_NUMBER" cookie with count, with expiration, lets say for 2 full weeks.
setcookie("VISIT_NUMBER",1 + $visitcount, time() + 3600*24*14);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a cookies system is that people can easily delete cookies, and many programs will automatically delete cookies after a day, week, month, etc.  You can use a persons IP address instead and keep track of it in a XML file or in a database, but be aware that this can change as well.

The best solution you have for a system like this is to make people log in to your system and only track the people who are logged in.  In that case, you can keep track of the logged in persons IP address and the time of their visit.  You can also impliment both a cookie and a database system, but something that complex may not be feasable for a smaller site.

If you are going to stick with the cookie, you can either make a whole new cookie with the timestamp each time the user visits your site and count the number of cookies, or you can create one cookie that increments everytime the datastamp changes dramatically (signaling another visit).  You can make it so if the person visits twice within a 5 minute period, that it only counts as 1 visit, and other technical stuff like that.

If you would like to use the database, just include a file in the footer that logs the persons IP address (or username even better) and the timestamp at which they visit.